# How to Read and Use Integer value from Core Data

Tags: core-data, xcode5

I will reframe the question:

I use **Core Data** and I define an Entity with an Attribute: **attribute1** as **Integer16**.

I read the attribute:

```
NSArray *objects = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

int integer1 = [[objects valueForKey:@"attribute1"] integerValue]
```

In this last sentence App crashes.

The aim is to realise the arithmetic:

```
int integer2 = 0;

integer2 = integer2 + integer1;
```

Maybe I must work with NSNumber, NSInteger, NSUInteger?

Really, I do not understand how something so simple is so complicated with Objective C.

No comment...

Original question:

First, I work with XCode 5 (iOS 7)

I have defined an Entity with an Attribute **countStep** as **Integer 16**. In that attribute I have saved a value (i.e. 10)

Later, I want to read that value:

```
int integerVal1 = [[objects valueForKey:@"countStep"] integerValue];
```

With the intention to realise arithmetic operations:

```
int integerVal2;

integerVal2 = integerVal2 + integerVal1
```

But in source line:

```
int integerVal1 = [[objects valueForKey:@"countStep"] integerValue];
```

App crashes with error message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have tried several alternatives.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int integerVal2;
```

Or:

```
NSString *string = [[objects valueForKey:@"countStep"]description];

int integerVal1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[string intValue]];

integerVal2 = integerVal2 + integerVal1
```

The problem is the same: convert a dictionary object to primitive element int (integer) to compute arithmetic operations: integerVal2 = integerVal2 + integerVal1

Any idea?

Comment: The error says `countStep` is an array. How is it an array? How are you setting the value? Have you added any custom code to your entity?

Comment: countStep is the name of the Attribute in Core Data. The question is: how can I realise sums with an integer (i.e. 10, 5 or whatever) saved in Core Data?

Comment: Being an Integer 16 as you describe is correct. But the runtime says you haven't done that - hence the exception.

Comment: I will reframe the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: How are you setting the number and saving it to core data?

Comment: [objects setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:integerVariable]  forKey:@"attribute1"];

Answer (score 2):

Ok, reading your code carefully... This:

```
NSArray *objects = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

int integer1 = [[objects valueForKey:@"attribute1"] integerValue]
```

will never work, because calling `valueForKey:` on an array returns an array. So when you call `integerValue` you get an exception.

What you should do is:

```
NSArray *objects = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
id myEntity = objects[0]; // put protection around this...
int integer1 = [[myEntity valueForKey:@"attribute1"] integerValue]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was my problem: how to convert the returned array value (calling valueForKey) to a primitive value (int). Because when I saw the Debug Area, I saw the value (3 i.e.) rounded by "()".

Comment: Repeat, thank you very much mr. Wain! Works perfect! The key is: **id myEntity = objects[0];**       Too bad I did not find any information about this sentence and I have lost 2 days.    Repeat, thank you very much!